# Error generating PDF417 with TCPDF using 13 digits

Tags: php, barcode, tcpdf, pdf417

well, I have a very strange problem generating 2D-Barcodes (PDF417) with PHP using TCPDF ([TCPDF-Website](http://www.tcpdf.org/)). This is my small code:

```
<?php
require_once ("tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php");
$type = "PDF417";
$code="123456789012";
$barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode($code, $type);
$barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG();
?>
```

This code works well and generates the barcode. But when I change the line with the code in

```
$code="1234567890123";
```

it does not generate any output. I tried several strings and found out, that everytime I try to use a string with more than 12 digits following one after the other I get no output. It does not depend on which position the digits were.

For example:

```
$code="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789012abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

works finde, but

```
$code="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890123abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

fails.

I use tcpdf 6.0.037 and also tried to download it from annother source. I even tried Version 6.0.020 - no change.
Server is openSuSE 12.2 64bit , PHP 5.3.15

Edit:
It's getting really strange: I tried annother barcode generator - and I get the same error. This one provides a online demo. When I fill in 1234567890123 online, I get the appropreate barcode. But on my own server the same string does not work.

```
"123456-7890123" works
"1234567890123" does not work
"123456789012" works
"12e34567890123" works
"123456789012sometext123456789012" works
"123456789012sometext1234567890123" does not work
```

Every string with more than 12 numbers in a row does not work - no matter how long the string is.

U see what I mean with "strange" ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this problem. We are using PDF417 & QR Code barcodes. I have not found a great solution for this, but I have found a solution that works for now. If anyone has a better solution, please advise.

**Problem:**
In our barcodes we have phone numbers that are stored and sometimes they are 13 digits or longer. The 13 digit phone number was causing the barcode to not print correctly.

**Solution:**
Since the barcode would not print due to this we just add a space every 10 digits and this keeps the barcode intact and our software can read in the phone number without spaces so we should be A-OK!

**Example Phone Number:** 
123456789012345 (15 digits)

**PHP Code to run on phone number:**
$phone = chunk_split($phone, 10, ' ');

**Example Phone Number after split:**
1234567890 12345

The libraries for these barcodes (Google/TCPDF) don't like numbers longer than 12 so it's definitely strange, but maybe I"m missing something easy to see.

Thanks and hope this helps someone.